# UITextField content gets lost when the view is scrolled off the screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a custom UITableViewCell prototype containing UITextField. I am adding new cells automatically when filling the UITextField in the last section. Where there are more sections that do not fit on one screen and I add another one, it gets filled with values from the first section and the first section inputs are emptied!

Screenshots:

[image: first step]

[image: added fourth row - it contains a!]

[image: first row is empty!]

Related code:

```
@implementation TMNewTripPeopleViewController

@synthesize sectionsCount = _sectionsCount;
@synthesize firstCellShowed = _firstCellShowed;

- (int) sectionsCount
{
    if (_sectionsCount == 0) {
        _sectionsCount = 1;
    }
    return _sectionsCount;
}

- (IBAction)inputChanged:(id)sender {
    UITextField* input = (UITextField*) sender;
    NSIndexPath* indexPathName = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:input.tag - 1];
    UITableViewCell* cellName = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathName];

    if (input == [cellName viewWithTag:input.tag]) {
        // last name input - add next section?
        if (input.tag == self.sectionsCount) {
            if (input.text.length > 0) {
                self.sectionsCount++;
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:self.sectionsCount - 1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            }
        }
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sectionsCount;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PersonName";
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        CellIdentifier = @"PersonEmail";
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITextField* input = (UITextField*) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.section + 1];
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 && !self.firstCellShowed) {
        [input becomeFirstResponder];
        self.firstCellShowed = YES;
    }

    [cell viewWithTag:1].tag = indexPath.section + 1;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your implementation. You generally set your cell's display values in this method.

When you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` (and you almost always should) then your cells will be reused when the table view is scrolled. If you don't update their values in `willDisplayCell` then they will show whatever values they previously had before reuse (if any).

Comment: So I should save these values in a model associated by a cell row + section every time they change?

Comment: Yes definitely do that. You may want to checkout this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561424/uitableview-tutorial